# How to calculate or at least constraint the value of tags defined in a stereotype?

Tags: rhapsody, sysml

To prioritize the engineering effort around `Requirement`s in a defined way, I came to the idea to use the information already added for the FMEA.

For this I have created a `Stereotype` named `fmeaRelevant` (will be named better later), which has several `Tag`s.

My target now is to first calculate the averages of all of these `Tag`s and then from these the average `RPN`, which is again a `Tag`.

For this, I have already created a `ConstrainedProperty`, which has the respective `ConstrainedParameter`s and `Constraints`.

`BindingConnector`s are created between the `ConstrainedParameter`s of the `ConstraintProperty` and the `Tag`s of the `Stereotype`.

The `Stereotype` is assigned to my `Requirement`s.

However, `Open ConstraintView ...` does not show me anything.

Is there anything I am missing?

P.S.: I am not sure how to provide something like a source code snippet for model content. If one makes a proposal in a comment, I will add this.

Answer (score 1):

You used binding connectors between stereotype properties and constraint parameters? That should not be possible, since they are on different levels. The parameters are on the model level and the stereotype properties are on the language level.

Of course, Rhapsody sometimes allows strange things, so it might well be, that there is a way to get it running.

The `RPN` relates to an actual hazordous situation. Your model describes this situation and all values relating to the situation should therefore be value properties of the FMEAitem. This element would be defined in a library. By the way, this is how it's done in the new [RAAML-specification](https://omg.org/spec/RAAML), which might be a useful reference.

Comment: Thanks for the great hint with RAAML!
I will take a look into it.
For now I did not mark your answer as "the answer", because I have to check whether this allows me to calculate the RPNs in Rhapsody.